# Creating an APK using Cordova\phonegap - display it on lockscreen

Tags: android, ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins, lockscreen

i am new at building apps using phonegap and my last one is an app that shows information VIA WS ( basiclly it's a web app ) and been built on phonegap to APK file - and it works good.
i would like as an option to set the App ( wich will run on the Background ) on android LOCKScreen and dont know where to start...
thank you

Answer (score 0):

The only way to put an app on the lock screen, that I know of, is to design it as widget. For example you can have a look at [google documentation](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/widgets.html).

As far as I know at the moment there is no way to put an Android webview inside a widget and that is what you would essentially need to do. You should also see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25938933/android-widget-using-cordova?answertab=votes#tab-top) SO question.

Hope this is a start for you ;-)

Comment: If this helps answering your question, can you please also accept the answer :)