# Is it possible to create home screen widgets for Android using Ionic Framework or React Native?

Tags: android-widget, ionic-framework, react-native, android-appwidget

Widgets are android native constructs that extend a view on the application screen.

Is it possible build a homescreen widget using Ionic or react native?

Comment: Can you please tell me how you implemented it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure but i have found a plugin that can extend the native view to the cordova app. 
You can install this plugin by

> cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-ace

For more info please follow this [repo link](https://github.com/microsoft/ace)

Comment: Hey, were you able to implement it in ionic?

Comment: @MayankKataria No. I haven't looked at ionic for a long time.

Answer (score 5):

Not sure about React Native, but I'll answer regarding Ionic.

In one word - no, you can't.

Ionic is an HTML, CSS, JS framework but it is mostly used with Cordova which embeds the webview in your app and renders HTML, CSS, JS in it.
(Answered  on [Quora](https://www.quora.com/Is-it-possible-to-create-home-screen-widgets-for-Android-using-Ionic-Framework))

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25938933/android-widget-using-cordova) you can find more thorough explanation for a similar question.

Answer (score 3):

It is possible, but you still would have to rely a lot on some Android notions. Here it is a proof of concept you can start with:

[React Native Android Widget Proof of Concept](https://github.com/netbeast/react-native-android-widget-poc)

Answer (score 1):

For React Native, at the moment this is not possible. There is an [issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/4377) on their GitHub, and upvotes for this feature are welcome on the [dedicated ProductPains page](https://react-native.canny.io/feature-requests/p/android-home-screen-widget).

Probably this will eventually be implemented.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible and not difficult to do with my project for **Android** in a very simple way without **plugin** with nothing. What I did I created my **AppWidget** in **Android Studio** modified the way I wanted. After I created it, I went to my project **Ionic I managed the android platform** then just copied the **class java** and **layouts  .xml** then pasted on **platform/android**.

> With this I adapted according to my need in my case
>   res/xml, res/layouts, res/drawable and in folders
>   src/the_application_address after I just needed to hit my Manisfest.