# Cordova Phonegap plugin to create floating window outside the app

Tags: cordova, background, window, phonegap, floating

Juste searched the all internet to find a way to create a floating window accessible outside my Cordova app.

Exactly the same as Floatube app does (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.heroofthesun.floatube this app is a Youtube app, and as you can't play video in background when app is in background, Floatube uses the float window to do the trick: check out )

Is it possible ? Any idea on how to do this ?
Thanks in advance guys

Cheers
Gilles

Answer (score 0):

Widgets are native Android constructions. But you CAN create your widget for your app with the help of cordova plugin called "cordova-plugin-ace". Made by Microsoft and opened to everyone.

Documentation:

Official site - [http://microsoft.github.io/ace/](http://%20http://microsoft.github.io/ace/)

Doc for creating widget - http://microsoft.github.io/ace/docs/native-ui/#four

Source -> [Android Widget using Cordova](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25938933/android-widget-using-cordova)